# Windows 10 GPO Ease of access disables background by default

Tags: windows, group-policy, desktop, image, background

I have deployed a specific desktop background image for all users of our domain via GPOs. This does work like a charm, yet "ease of access" defaults displaying of a desktop background image to "disabled", so I have to enable it manually for every user/ machine.

Is there a way I can enable this via GPO or PowerShell script?

Comment: EoA can disable the background image if it is required for the user to be able to see the icons on the desktop properly (so this is desired behaviour). The question is why EoA thinks that all of your users need this accomodation, and solve that, not how to work around EoA.

Comment: @SimonRichter I have set the start and accent color to RGB black. Does EoA decide that it's best to disable the desktop background image by my color of choice then?

Comment: I'm not that deep into the internals of EoA, but in general I'd expect that if the colors are set through EoA, then the entire visual design gets overridden (so you have a consistent set rather than e.g. a system setting of black background and an EoA setting of black text). EoA is generally not meant to be used through GPO (I'm amazed it even works, and would consider that a bug), because it's a per-user accomodation.